# Googletagmanager with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Can someone explain how should we properly integrate Googletagmanager with Turbolinks?

On normal pages we just copy/paste this code immediatelly after after the opening  tag.

```
  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-******"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
  <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); //f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-******');</script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

If I copy this code inside Turbolinks powered page I can see there is only one network request (when page loads for the first time)

Answer (score 4):

I got page refreshes working following [this guide](http://dan-russell.com/2013/07/google-tag-manager-for-single-page-applications/)

It suggests that you set up a virtual *url macro* and *pageview rule* in Tag Manager, and then push it to the dataLayer:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
  dataLayer.push({
    'event':'pageview',
    'virtualUrl': window.location.pathname
  });
});
```

Comment: This works for me. I'm trying to solve the issue of loading the GTM code on every page load because Turbolinks is inserting the DOM from the new page (and it's in the `<body>` tag).

Answer (score 1):

Implement google tag manager with turbolink 5.
copy the code below and paste  inside the head.

```
        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <% if Rails.env.production? %>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
          var url = event.data.url;

          dataLayer.push({
            'event':'pageView',
            'virtualUrl': url
          });
        });

        (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','[YOUR-GTM-ID]');
        </script>
        <% end %>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind events with Turbolinks to page:load (as opposed to `$(document).ready`)

```
$( window ).on( 'page:load', function () {
  // Do something
} );
```

[Google Tag Manager's documentation](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2772448?hl=en-GB) specifies:

> Google Tag Manager supports dynamic pages through events.

They provide some documentation about events here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events - but the specific implementation will depend on what you're doing with GTM.

Comment: I just want to have basic functionality of GTM. Are there any calls which should be called on "page:load"? 
On Google Analytics - I normally have to call "_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/url/of/page']);" on every "page:load"

Answer (score 0):

The two existing answers are incomplete. Here is the full solution, along with information on how to configure GTM for your change:

Add this to your site:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).on('page:change', function(){
         var url = window.location.href;

         dataLayer.push({
             'event':'pageView',
             'virtualUrl': url
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Once you've done that, register the trigger in Google Tag Manager and associate that trigger with the desired tags.

The complete instructions are available here: http://labs.wrprojects.com/how-to-use-google-tag-manager-with-rails-and-turbolinks/

Comment: If you're using turbolinks 5 (default in rails 5), the event changed to `turbolinks:load` instead of `page:change`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried this with Realtime, and it does change the URL.