# How to fire an event to use google tagmanager with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-tag-manager, turbolinks

I am trying to implement google tagmanager with a rails application, and am having trouble firing its tags because of turbolinks.

I have seen this answer: [Firing tags in GTM (Google Tag Manager) containers under turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948288/firing-tags-in-gtm-google-tag-manager-containers-under-turbolinks)
and this: [Googletagmanager with Turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530082/googletagmanager-with-turbolinks)
That tell me that I need to trigger an event on page:load, but I can't seem to trigger the event.
I have tried putting

```
$( window ).on( 'page:load', function () {
  dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});
} );
```

in the application.js file, as well as putting it in the views, and I have also tried through coffeescript with variations of this in a coffeescript anayltics file:

```
ready = ->
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'event_name'});
$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

But I still can't get the google tagmanager to fire its tags when I move to another page because of turbolinks.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This code only puts the event into the dataLayer. What rules and tags have you put into GTM to handle this event?

Comment: I have a tag for CrazyEgg and have included as a firing rule 'GTM Event' which has as its rule {{event}} contains 'event_name' - is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. When you move to another page, open your browser's JavaScript console and enter "dataLayer" to display the contents of the dataLayer object. You will see several sub-objects. If you open the fourth object, what is the event type? Do you see any additional sub-objects? What are their event types?

Comment: There are eight objects: the fourth object says: event: "gtm.dom". The "event_name" I am actually using is the word "contratado" (both in the code and GTM). There are several other objects, of which the 2nd, 3rd and 7th all have event: "contratado". Object 5 has "event: gym.load", object 6 has "event: gtm.js" and 8 and 9 which have event: "event_name".  Additionally, before load the console prints: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined . Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry - my comment above is incorrect - what I meant to say was this:There are eight objects: the fourth object says: event: "gtm.dom". The "event_name" I am actually using is the word "contratado" (both in the code and GTM). There are several other objects, of which the 2nd, 3rd, 6th, 7th and 8th all have event: "contratado". All have _proto_ beneath that. Additionally, before load the console prints: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined . Thanks for your help

Comment: In my experience, the first three events should be gtm.js, gtm.dom, and gtm.load. Do you see the 5 contratado events after moving one page? If so, you are calling dataLayer.push() too frequently. Also, it is possible that the JS error is causing your tags not to fire. Unfortunately I'm not going to be able to help you with that with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Virtual page view to track turbo links page loads. Add the following script just before the head close tag. Modified the default GTM script so it will work with turbo links.

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager trigger for Turbolinks -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('page:change', function(){
   var url = window.location.href;
   var data = {
    'event':'pageView',
    'virtualUrl': url
   };
   if(window['referer'] !== undefined){
      data['pageReferrer'] = window['referer'];
   }else{
      data['pageReferrer'] = document.referrer;
   }
   dataLayer.push(data);
   window['referer'] = window.location.href;
 });
 </script>
 <!-- End Google Tag Manager trigger for Turbolinks -->
```